# QPainter::end() slow when multiple QGLWidgets visible

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In my MDI sub-window GUI I have two tabs: in one tab is a single large `QGLWidget` derived class, and in the other four `QGLWidget`s separated by splitters.  They each have their own OpenGL contexts (for the actual painting), share another across all 5 (for geometry data), and share one application-wide (for shaders).

When drawing in the single viewport tab, it's very fast as expected; but when drawing in the quad view (each viewport is updated from a timer in creation order), the rendering speed plummets and gets worse with each viewport as the list is iterated through.

I began to profile and narrowed down the search to a `Qt` call that was taking so much longer in quad view than single view:

```
QPainter::end();
```

So when only the large single viewport is visible, I get `QPainter::end()` timings (in microseconds) like this:

```
Total time(us): 981
Number of calls: 32
Average call time(us): 30.656250
```

Quite reasonable.  But when I switch to the quad view:

```
Viewport 1:
Total time(us): 196023
Number of calls: 32
Average call time(us): 6125.718750

Viewport 2:
Total time(us): 509769
Number of calls: 32
Average call time(us): 15930.281250

Viewport 3:
Total time(us): 518504
Number of calls: 32
Average call time(us): 16203.250000

Viewport 4:
Total time(us): 518226
Number of calls: 32
Average call time(us): 16194.562500
```

Vastly longer for what is supposed to be the same amount of work.  Even stranger, is that it increases 200x(!), and then 2.5x for the next viewport before stabilising.  If I run the tests for longer they give almost exactly the same readings - it doesn't increase any further.

The `QPainter` code in question is simply:

```
QPainter p;
p.begin( this );
p.beginNativePainting();
glUseProgram( program_ );

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer2d_->texture() );
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer3d_->texture() );

surfaceBuf_.bind();
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4 );
surfaceBuf_.unbind();

p.endNativePainting();
p.end();
```

I browsed through the source code of the `QPainter::end()` and `QOpenGLPaintEngine::end()`, but it just seems to be state reversion and making sure the draw queue has been flushed.  Considering I don't set any state requests, or do any drawing through Qt (all my calls are raw OpenGL) - it shouldn't have anything to do.

Why does the time increase even though the `QPainter` instance is created on the stack, and each viewport is doing the same amount of work?

Comment: If you're going to overpaint a QGLWidget I would recommend doing all the QPainter calls (including instantiation) after your openGL calls and AFTER you clear your current OpenGL state. (no need for the beginNativeRendering(), endNativeRendering() calls.) Also, 6 contexts might severly limit the memory available to each context depending on your GPU  architecture and RAM capacity.

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar Thanks for the advice, I'll give it ago when I come back to this problem.  Nice Mitchell & Webb reference by the way!